# Error: Is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, html

I've used a multidimensional array in javascript to store data which I use to generate content dynamically, and it works fine in any webkit browser as well as firefox and IE 9 and up but for some reason IE 8 (where i tested it) and IE 7 (which I emulated) gives me an error "is null or not an object" on the following code:

```
var data =
        [
        ["A","X",[5,6],3,2014],
        ["V","L",[9,10],4,2014],
        ["X","N",[10,11],6,2014]
        ];
for(var t=0;t<data.length;t++){
  if(data[t][3]==i){
     alert("Found");
   }
}
```

The error specifically says '3' is null or not an object and refers to the 3 in the if statement. Could the error be because i don't declare the array as

```
var data=new Array();
```

or is there another problem?

additional Info: This code is in a document ready event for jQuery.

Comment: The code snippet you have provided runs fine. Paste it into your console, hit enter and you will see that no errors are produced.

Comment: What is `i` in this case? Has it been declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question doesn't produce that error, but if you have a trailing comma after the last item in the array, it will:

```
var data =
    [
    ["A","X",[5,6],3,2014],
    ["V","L",[9,10],4,2014],
    ["X","N",[10,11],6,2014],
    ];
for(var t=0;t<data.length;t++){
  if(data[t][3]==i){
     alert("Found");
   }
}
```

In IE8 and earlier, that array will have four items instead of three, and the last item will be undefined. When `t` is `3`, `data[t]` will return `undefined`, and applying the `[3]` to that will case that error message. It says that " '3' is null or not an object" because `3` is the index that you used to get the value that isn't an object.

Comment: I didnt post the whole array since it is very large it seems I just forgot to take the trailing comma out.

Comment: Nevermind there was no trailing comma earlier but i arranged the data and it seems i forgot about that one, there goes 3 hours of my life cause of a comma, I feel stupid.

Answer (score 0):

My original comment missed the fact that you are running this in IE7. In that case the answer is you haven't defined `i`

My console in IE7 specifically says `"'i' is undefined"`

Comment: Sorry but `i` is defined I just didnt post it

Comment: @user2994389 - anything else you didn't post?

Comment: the data array is info about events the last 3 elements is the date of the event, `i` is the current month, looping through the data I check if `i` is the same as the events month, I add a tooltip dynamically where that `alert` is.

Answer (score 0):

I test the array in IE7 & IE8, it works fine. cause of "i" ?

```
if($.type(data[t]) == 'array' && data[t][3] == i)
```